# Filter outcome from pandas.groupby on same line

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

How to filter data frame based on the output of the groupby transformation in one line.

So far I got the following, which works, but I want to know if there is a easier/more efficient way.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two'], 'B': [1, 1, 6, 6]})

df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].sum()>10).groupby('A').B.sum()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.groupby('A').sum().loc[lambda x : x['B']>10]
Out[251]: 
      B
A      
two  12
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `query` for readability:

```
df.groupby('A').sum().query('B > 10')
```

Output:

```
      B
A      
two  12
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way not readable but quite performant:

```
df[(lambda a, b: np.bincount(a, b)[a] >= 10)
     (df.A.factorize()[0], df.B.values)].groupby('A').sum()
```

---

```
     B
A      
two  12
```